# Do coaxial rotor helicopters have a size limit?

Tags: helicopter

Why haven't there been heavy helicopters like the CH53 with coaxial rotor configuration? Is there any physical limitation inherent to the concept?

I recall someone at Sikorsky saying that their new X2 coaxial helicopters that they built for FARA competition, etc. don't scale up to heavy helicopters. But it is likely that they only meant the high speed compound mechanic and not coaxial rotors as a whole.

Comment: Does [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/50917/64684) answer your question?

Comment: So what I understand from this is that the difficulty in creating enough differential pitch with increasing interaction between the rotors and the bending forces on the rotorshaft while experiencing dissymmetry of lift are the reasons? Am I getting that right?